# C++ Recursion Function implementation in a graph

Tags: c++, recursion, graph-theory

I am trying to implement an algorithm in a C++ program which initially has to traverse each and every edge in the graph. In the graph I am starting my search from the output port and then heading towards my input port. If I find that one of my nodes has an outdegree greater than 1, I call a recursion function which traverses the outdegree and should give me the largest value among them. Unfortunately my code is not working as desired.

The code is here as follows-

```
if(graph.gate_list.at(check).OutEdgeCount()>1) //Suppose a node has more than one output   edge, then we need to find the maximum delay for that node before moving upwards
{
    p_edge_check=p_edge;
    p_edge= graph.gate_list.at(check).first_out_edge;
    stack<Edge<delay_type, error_type>* > keep_edge, keep_edge1;
    for(int index=0; index<11; index++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j< 10; j++)
        {
            gate_stack_temp.push_back(temp2);
        }
        while(!keep_edge1.empty())
        {
            p_edge= keep_edge1.top();
            p_edge->active=true;
            keep_edge1.pop();
        }
        delay_gate[path_index][index] = /*delay_gate[path_index][index] +*/ Recursion_Loop(graph,gate_stack_temp, p_edge, keep_edge, keep_edge1, delay_temp, index);

        gate_stack[index][path_index].assign(gate_stack_temp[0].front(), gate_stack_temp[0].back());

        gate_stack_temp.clear();
        p_edge=p_edge_check;
        for(int i=0; i<delay_temp.size(); i++) 
        {
            delay_temp[i]=0;
        }
    }
    while(!keep_edge1.empty())
    {
        keep_edge1.pop();
    }
    p_edge=p_edge_check;
}
```

The above was the code where I call the recursion function called Recursion Loop. Below I am attaching the actual Recursion function-

```
double Recursion_Loop(Graph<delay_type, error_type, power_type, mask_type> &graph, vector<vector<int> > &gate_stack_temp, Edge<delay_type, error_type> *p_edge,  stack<Edge<delay_type, error_type>* > &keep_edge, stack<Edge<delay_type, error_type>* > &keep_edge1, vector<double> &delay_temp, int index)
{
    Edge<delay_type, error_type> *p_edge_temp, *p_edge_check;
    if(!FindPathLoop1(keep_edge,p_edge)) 
    {
        keep_edge.push(p_edge);
    }
    if(!FindPathLoop1(keep_edge1,p_edge)) 
    {
        keep_edge1.push(p_edge);
    }
    int temp_path = 0;

    while(p_edge!=NULL)
    {
        if(graph.gate_list.at(p_edge->head_index).OutEdgeCount() > 0)
        {
            p_edge= graph.gate_list.at(p_edge->head_index).first_out_edge;
            if(FindPathLoop2(gate_stack_temp,p_edge->head_index,temp_path))
            {
                p_edge=p_edge->same_tail_next;
                if(p_edge==NULL) 
                {
                    goto point1;
                }
                /*if(graph.gate_list.at(p_edge->head_index).OutEdgeCount() < 0)
                p_edge_temp = p_edge->same_tail_next;
                if(p_edge_temp==NULL)
                return graph.gate_list.at(p_edge->head_index).delay.at(index) + p_edge->delay;
                else p_edge= p_edge_temp;
                if(!p_edge->active) return graph.gate_list.at(p_edge->head_index).delay.at(index) + p_edge->delay;
                */

                if(!FindPathLoop1(keep_edge1,p_edge)) 
                {
                    keep_edge1.push(p_edge);
                }
                p_edge->active=false;
                delay_temp[temp_path] = delay_temp[temp_path] + p_edge->delay + graph.gate_list.at(p_edge->tail_index).delay.at(index)+ Recursion_Loop(graph, gate_stack_temp, p_edge, keep_edge, keep_edge1, delay_temp, index);
                p_edge= keep_edge.top();
                keep_edge.pop();
                gate_stack_temp[temp_path].push_back(p_edge->head_index);
            }
            else
            {
                if(!FindPathLoop1(keep_edge1,p_edge)) 
                {
                    keep_edge1.push(p_edge);
                }
                p_edge->active=false;
                if(graph.gate_list.at(p_edge->head_index).OutEdgeCount() ==0 )
                {
                    if(FindPathLoop2(gate_stack_temp,p_edge->head_index,temp_path)) 
                    {
                        gate_stack_temp[temp_path].push_back(p_edge->head_index);
                    }
                    return (p_edge->delay + graph.gate_list.at(p_edge->head_index).delay.at(index));
                }
                else 
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            p_edge= p_edge->same_tail_next;
            if(delay_temp[temp_path] > delay_temp[0])
            {
                delay_temp[0]= delay_temp[temp_path];
                while(!gate_stack_temp[0].empty())
                {
                    gate_stack_temp[0].pop_back();
                }
                while(!gate_stack_temp[temp_path].empty())
                {
                    gate_stack_temp[0].push_back(gate_stack_temp[temp_path].back());
                    gate_stack_temp[temp_path].pop_back();
                }
            }
            else if(temp_path!=0)
            {
                while(!gate_stack_temp[temp_path].empty())
                {
                    gate_stack_temp[temp_path].pop_back();
                }
            }
            temp_path++;
        }
        /*if(delay_temp[0] > delay_temp[temp_path])
        {
        delay_temp[0]= delay_temp[temp_path];
        while(!gate_stack_temp[0].empty())
        gate_stack_temp[0].pop_back();
        while(!gate_stack_temp[temp_path].empty())
        {
        gate_stack_temp[0].push_back(gate_stack_temp[temp_path].back());
        gate_stack_temp[temp_path].pop_back();
        }
        }*/
```

point1:
    return delay_temp[0];
    }

Since I am new to C++ (and graph theory with previously only a basic knowledge of C), I believe that maybe my approach here is hindering the output. I would be really glad if someone could take a look at this code. I have been at it for weeks without any result and hence had to ask for help now.

Edit: Here are the FindPathLoop functions that have been called as well-

```
    bool FindPathLoop(vector<vector<vector<int> > > &gate_stack, int gate_index, int path_index)
    {
        vector<int> temp;

        while(!gate_stack[0][path_index].empty())
        {
            if(gate_index == gate_stack[0][path_index].back())
            {
                while(!temp.empty())
                {   
                    gate_stack[0][path_index].push_back(temp.back());
                    temp.pop_back();
                }
                return true;
            }
            temp.push_back(gate_stack[0][path_index].back());
            gate_stack[0][path_index].pop_back();
        }

        while(!temp.empty())
        {
            gate_stack[0][path_index].push_back(temp.back());
            temp.pop_back();
        }
        return false;
    }

     bool FindPathLoop1(stack<Edge<delay_type, error_type>* > &keep_edge, Edge<delay_type, error_type> *p_edge)
     {
           stack<Edge<delay_type, error_type>* > temp;
           while(!keep_edge.empty())
           {
               if(p_edge == keep_edge.top())
               {
                   while(!temp.empty())
                   {
                       keep_edge.push(temp.top());
                       temp.pop();
                   }
                   return true;
               }
               temp.push(keep_edge.top());
               keep_edge.pop();
           }
           while(!temp.empty())
           {
               keep_edge.push(temp.top());
               temp.pop();
           }
           return false;
       }

     bool FindPathLoop2(vector<vector<int> > &gate_stack, int gate_index, int path_index)
     {
        vector<int> temp;

        while(!gate_stack[path_index].empty())
        {
            if(gate_index == gate_stack[path_index].back())
            {
                while(!temp.empty())
                {
                    gate_stack[path_index].push_back(temp.back());
                    temp.pop_back();
                }
                return true;
            }
            temp.push_back(gate_stack[path_index].back());
            gate_stack[path_index].pop_back();
        }

        while(!temp.empty())
        {
            gate_stack[path_index].push_back(temp.back());
            temp.pop_back();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Start with a very simple graph, and step through the code line by line in a debugger.

Comment: Have you tried implementing a BFS/DFS? For non-connected graphs, you can always sum the rows/columns of the adjacency matrix to find the connected parts. Also, it's clearer for everyone if you say "digraph", if the edges are directed. Could you explain what is this input/output port, and gates, and delays?

Comment: I am trying to implement a different algorithm which I believe is faster than BFS/DFS, hence comes the problem. The following graph has been derived from a VHDL netlist and hence input/output port, gates are part of the hardware circuit and the corresponding gate delays are the physical parameters we are trying to work on.

Comment: As Joachim says, use a debugger. You have too much code and no data in your question for anyone to make any sensible suggestions. One thing I would suggest is that you get into the habit of using `{ }` with indentation. Also space things out a bit, the code looks too dense and is hard to read (at least, to me).

Comment: Thank You Joachim, after debugging with a simple graph, the code worked.